# jquery/javascript remove item from array in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
Class CategoryInfo
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Name As String
    Public Categories As List(Of CategoryInfo)
    Public TreeLevel As Integer
End Class 

var tree as CategoryInfo
```

I want to remove item in array by index. However `tree.indexOf` returns `-1` for item in `tree.Categories`.

How can I find item from array in array?

for example

```
array:findData
{Id: 341, Name: "ציוד אלקטרוני", Categories: Array(2), TreeLevel: 1} 
0:
{Id: 348, Name: "אביזרי יצור", Categories: null, TreeLevel: 2}
1:
{Id: 344, Name: "חלקי CDMA", Categories: null, TreeLevel: 2}
javascript:
function findName(findData, dataCategoria) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataCategoria.length; i++) {
            if (dataCategoria[i].Categories != null) {
                findName(findData, dataCategoria[i].Categories)
            }
            if (!dataCategoria[i].Name.includes($("#FindText").val())) {
                if (findData.find(dataCategoria[i]) > -1) {
                    findData.splice(findData.indexOf(dataCategoria[i]), 1);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Can you past your code here?

Comment: That is clearly not Javascript code. Please update your title and tags.

Comment: tag this question as VBscript.

Comment: the code is javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jquery sample code for removing element from an array.

```
var y = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
var removeItem = 2;

y = jQuery.grep(y, function(value) {
  return value != removeItem;
});
```

Here is a Js Sample code.

```
var array = [2, 5, 9];
var index = array.indexOf(5);

if (index > -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: This would be ideal, but the code in the OP is not JS. The OP seems a little confused.

Comment: it is jquery not js

Comment: Well jQuery ***is*** JS, but the OP is neither of those things, despite the title and tags.

Comment: i have updated the code. you can check another method. yes you are write jquery is js but jquery is library built on top of js. and js is core.

Comment: You're not getting what I'm saying. Your code is absolutely fine. My point is that *the OP is not using JS or jQuery *at all** despite what their question says.

Comment: ohhh sorry... ive got your point. seems like he had put it under wrong section it looks like VB or something.